# Unable to set the private key in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have stored our Digi certificates having a private key in HashiCorp Vault. It contains thee things: certificate, name, private key.

I am trying to read the data and return new x509 certificate using a .NET Core standard project:

```
var crypto = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parms);
crypto.FromXmlString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(certificationvalue.Data.PrivateKey)));

x509.PrivateKey = crypto; // getting error that operation is not allowed on this platform.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Ok then, what platform do you use?

Comment: I have published my code into Pivotal cloud foundary usng .net core and windows stack.

Comment: Show us please full error message

Comment: Operation is not supported on this platform.","StackTrace":["at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.set_PrivateKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm value)","at